# How to create an in-app purchase greater than $18.99 in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I went to https://itunesconnect.apple.com to create my first in-app purchase product. In the dropdown for the price tier, the maximum tier is 19. This tier is $18.99 USD. How would I create a product that costs more than $18.99?

[image: tier 19]

I know that higher tiers exist because I've seen other apps like [Coffee Meets Bagel](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/coffee-meets-bagel-cmb-free/id630119301?mt=8) sell 3,000 beans for $24.99. Additionally, the [tier matrix](http://forecomm.mptw.fr/templates/PriceMatrix.html) shows a maximum tier of 87, which is $999.99.

[image]

Comment: That is strange. What browser are you using? I just went in and tested it and was able to see all tiers.

Comment: @Jsdodgers I am using Firefox 32.0.3 on Mac 10.9.5. Are you a long time user of iTunes Connect? Perhaps you need to become a reputable seller before Apple allows you to select higher tiers? This is my first time creating a product. Also, my type of product is "consumable". Is there a different maximum tier per type of product?

Comment: @Jsdodgers You are right about the browser. I switched to Chrome and saw all the tiers. Wow... Apple web engineers... :( You can write this as the answer and I will approve it.

Comment: You shouldn't use anything other than Safari when interacting with the developer portal or iTunes Connect.  Typical of Apple, they just don't care about technology that isn't theirs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely because of the browser you are using. I just tested this in Safari and I was able to see all of the tiers.